# Url rewrite does not work ubuntu server

Tags: 12.10, server, apache2, php, mod-rewrite

Currently I am working with a *php* script but it still contains an unfriendly link (`cms.php?Cms=login`).

I want to turn it into a friendly link

```
/cms/login
```

I have an `.htaccess` file is created

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cms/([^/]*)$ /cms.php?cms=$1 [L]
```

But when in now go to the page I see this:

[image]

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also did this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 reload
```

`rewrite.load` file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I looked on much forums but I cannot find it.
Ubuntu server works on *openvz* (ubuntu 12.10)

Where is the fault ? what should I do ?

Comment: In the screenshot you post, you're requesting URL `/cms/index.html/`, but your rewrite rule does not match it `^cms/([^/]*)$`. Please include in your question the exact requirement for your rewrite. What do you want to accomplish (and what you do not)? Do you want the full path after `/cms/` to be rewritten to a parameter? Or just the first word until the next `/`? It looks like you have a requirement about the slash, referring to your current regular expression.

Comment: I mean this one.
using the generator of http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^cms/([^/]*)$ /cms.php?cms=$1 [L]


http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj5uT.png

I want cms/login if this is probable.
But I am not sure if the rewrite function is working.

Comment: @DaanSeegers in your screen shot, you have `.html/` at the end of the link. According to your rewrite rule, it should be `/cms/login` instead of `/cms/login.html/`. Does your problem persist after you removed the `.html/`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cms\login$ cms.php?Cms=login [L]
</IfModule>
```

You should notice that you type `cms.php?Cms=login` with 'C' uppercase, it is different with 'c' in lowercase.